# i get value from scraping script more than one time

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I created scraping code for deals page on amazon the script worked but I get the value more than one time

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from setuptools.command import install
import requests
import html5lib
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\Compu City\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn')
time.sleep(10)
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML",'window.scrollBy(0,2000)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res , 'html5lib')
for x in soup.select('div',{'class':'a-section a-spacing-none tallCellView gridColumn5 singleCell'}):
    for y in x.select('button',{'class':'a-button-text a-text-center'}):
        if('Choose options' in y.text):
            for z in x.find_all('a', {'class': 'a-size-base a-link-normal dealTitleTwoLine singleCellTitle autoHeight'}):
                print(z.text)
driver.close()
```

i think that the problem from loop but idont know how to fix that

Comment: what you want to scrape ? There are many things on page what you targeting specifically

Comment: products which has link direct to product details page

Comment: Do you mean products which has button `choose option` if so then you are going wrong I guess, Every product will navigate you on product details page irrespective of button of button name

Comment: I get the right value which I want but the problem now that I get the value from (z.text) more than one time some of products name has print 10 times or more

Comment: what is meaning of this `if('Choose options' in y.text):`

Comment: the loop include many of products so i depend on button(choose options) to choose products which i want

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn&nocache=1584618882960        this is the link of page

Comment: exactly that what I said in my previous comments, check the buttons there are other button which you missed like `add to cart`, `see details`

Comment: I know that I just want ```Choose options```